# Excel Formula for Returning a Value

Tags: excel, match, formula, vlookup

I have a phone number list on sheet1, on sheet 2 in column A I have a list of area codes (0131), in column B I have the area name (Edin).

I am looking for the formula to be entered into sheet 1, which will look up on sheet 2 and return the correct area name (column B) for the area code.

The formula must look at the first 5 characters of the phone number field detailed in sheet 1.

Any help is appreciated
If I have not explained it enough please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would advise reading up on the VLOOKUP function.

Create a second column 'B' in sheet 1 using this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1, 5)
```

drag this down so that you now have the area numbers isolated.
next create a third column on sheet 1 and use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

This should take the area code you have isolated (A2) in sheet 1 and match it to a row on the array in sheet2 (Sheet2!A:B) and return the value on the second column (2), the FALSE indicates exact matches only.

If having issues e.g #N/A values for all rows please ensure the area numbers in sheet 2 and the isolated sheet numbers in sheet 1 are in the same format.